# How to check if the logged in user has permission to view a data field in apex code?

Tags: apex, permission-sets, clone

I need to create a custom Clone button to clone only data fields in which the logged in user has view permission to (in the his assigned permission set). how do I do that using the Apex class?

thanks!

Comment: use [isAccessible()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)  method

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

## 1 Using sObjectDescribeResult class:

Take object Account for instance, you can do something like this.

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Account.Description.getDescribe();
dfr.isAccessible(); //tells if the current user has acces to it or not.
```

## 2 Using SOQL:

Please refer to the following Salesforce blog: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html

Comment: Please include an example for 2 as well. Users should not have to follow any links off site for an answer to be effective.